# Removing Query Strings from the URL Using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to tidy up the analysis in Google Analytics by removing query strings from the URL, but this has split into three requirements;

1. I want to remove query strings from being displayed in the GA analysis.
2. Campaign UTMs still need to work.
3. Stop any PII gathered in a UTM from hitting GA.

I've found a number of JavaScript methods (attached below) that will do task 3, but I don't know whether this implementation will affect tasks 1 and 2.

This leads to my question;

**Will the JavaScript method stop all query strings from hitting GA entirely, and therefore break my campaign UTMs?**

Thanks for your help!

*JavaScript attached below*

```
function() {

var params = ['name', 'email'];
var a = document.createElement('a');
var param,
  qps,
  iop,
  ioe
  i;

a.href = {{Page URL}};

if (a.search) {

qps = '&' + a.search.replace('?', '') + '&';

for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {

  param = params[i];
  iop = qps.indexOf('&' + param + '=');

  if(iop > -1) {

    ioe = qps.indexOf('&', iop + 1);
    qps = qps.slice(0, iop) + qps.slice(ioe, qps.length);

  }

}

a.search = qps.slice(1, qps.length - 1);

}
 return a.href;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update the page location in the DOM with the result of a function like this (`window.location={{clean URL}}`) you would naturally cause a lot of problems by causing reloading.

If you use the result of this function to set UA parameters relating to page and referrer, then it affects nothing that isn't related to those parameters in the hits. For example, you would want to clean the `page` field which is not just on page hits:

[image]

Things like utm parameters are extracted from normal DOM/BOM (for example `window.location`) and [sent as separate parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cn) and are not calculated from [page related parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dp) later on the server side unless you are doing extraction yourself in Analytic's custom filters.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please excuse my ignorance, but could you clarify? How do I go about this? Do I use my existing JS or do I have to get another to produce this {{clean url}}?

Comment: I was using clean url as the name for your script if you defined it as a GTM customjs variable.. You could instead start with a URL-type variable if you wanted to strip all parameters and still not affect how UTM params get used per the other comments, but then you would probably still need to add back specific URL parameters you want to track, i.e. for site search.  What analytics params you want to override with filtered variable(s) and what level of filtering you want in the variable(s) are things you can handle and tune separately in the tags and variable definitions, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use Google Analytics built-in mechanics to drop URL parameters through setting up *Exclude URL Query Parameters* in View settings. Docs are here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en
No JS Required.