# How to remove URL Queries in Google Tag Manager for any tag (not only Google Analytics)?

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I found a few articles [and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716538/removing-query-strings-from-the-url-using-google-tag-manager) how to strip queries from URLs sent to Google Analytics. How about other services, like Facebook or Hotjar? Is there any way to send them clean URLs?

I aim to maximize the website visitors' privacy and to avoid accidental data leaks.

Answer (score 0):

That does not depend on Google Tag Manager, but on the respective tracking tags.

It works for Google Analytics because the "location" field is explicitly set and can be overridden. Other tags might not offer this as a feature - e.g. many marketing tags infer the page location from the referrer instead of having an option to set the value. Since the referrer is sent in a http header as part of the request for the marketing pixels, it is outside the domain of GTM to manipulate.